# How to edit text in a div thats in a div thats in another div with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know what javascript code I can use to edit the text of this word?
This is not a duplicate because this has multiple divs in a div. And the target word is located in a div that is inside the more divs.

```
<div id="jump">
  <div class="kick">
     <div class="meet">
        <div class="balls">
           <div class="word">
             Hello
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: You've put almost no effort into this question

Comment: he who googles well rules the world

Comment: Use a text editor. No javascript required.

Comment: What are you guys talking about?

Comment: What is the javascript code to replace the word?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the 1st element that has this class...

```
document.getElementsByClassName('word')[0].innerHTML='Goodbye';
```

It's the 5th element that has this tag...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[4].innerHTML='Goodbye';
```

Comment: When I execute that code I get this:

Comment: Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

Comment: <body onload="document.getElementsByClassName('word')[0].innerHTML='Goodbye';">

Comment: JavaScript is asynchronous so it runs faster than the HTML has time to load, so to stop it from doing so always place the JS in the document ONLOAD event.
In this example I’ll place a function name in the onload event that contains all my JS… <body onload="KickStart();">

Answer (score 0):

You can use next code:

```js
document.querySelector('.word').textContent = 'Hello World!';
```

```html
<div id="jump">
  <div class="kick">
     <div class="meet">
        <div class="balls">
           <div class="word">
             Hello
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

But if you has few elements with class word, function '`querySelectror` fining only first element'.If you need get many elements, you can use `document.querySelectorAll` --- is HTMLCollection (not array).
I don't recommend to use **getElementByClassName** - is very slowly method.
Method **getElementsByTagName** -faster that **querySelectorAll** , but it use only tagName. **getElementById** -is the fastest menthod  finding of elements. 
But that method find only first element with current ID.